# jquery selector doesn't give all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the next web page I want to select all `<li>` elements with Jquery.
I want to select all the products that are inside `<ul class=search-result-gridview-items">`
https://www.walmart.com/browse/home-improvement/air-quality/1072864_133032_1231459

I have tried:

```
$(".search-product-result ul li")
$("ul.search-result-gridview-items li")
```

Also I have tried:

```
$("li")
$("ul li")
$("section li")
```

to select all `<li>` and none works.
All of them give one `<li>` and not all.

Why this happens?

Comment: On the linked webpage, are you sure jQuery is loaded and that $ is not an alias for something else?

Comment: If you're using Chrome dev tools console, $ is equivalent to `document.querySelector()` and will only return the **first** element. If you had actual jQuery loaded your selectors would return all respective elements. jQuery might simply not be loaded on their page. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308588/simple-jquery-selector-only-selects-first-element-in-chrome)

Comment: does `$("li").length` returns 1 ?

Comment: post the html too :)

Comment: From close vote: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.**  It's not possible to reproduce your problem so any answer will be speculative at best (a lucky guess).  Please also read [mcve].

Comment: You can see the html of the page. Also try with the console in Chrome.          In this page that is in the same website of walmart.com it works. https://www.walmart.com/browse/home-improvement/air-conditioners/1072864_133032_133026/?cat_id=1072864_133032_133026#searchProductResult

Comment: If you compare the source of the two different pages, jQuery is referenced in the second one, but **not** in the first. This likely means the first page does **not** load jQuery at all, which is why the behavior is different on the first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the website is not using jQuery. `console.log(window.jQuery)` return undefined

Most probably the $ is bind to some function

You can use vanila javascript to get all elements using

```
document.querySelectorAll('ul.search-result-gridview-items li')
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is the actual HTML code that you've got in your site, the problem most likely is with the class declaration on the `<ul>`.

You have it noted as `<ul class=search-result-gridview-items">` when it should be `<ul class="search-result-gridview-items">`.

You're missing the opening double quotes before the class name.

Comment: That doesn't explain why `$("li")` only yields one item though.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol it might do - if everything after the missing quote is parsed as a big long string.

Comment: Without seeing a full sample of the HTML that the OP is working with, it's kind of a moot point. We're ultimately guessing.

Comment: If Chrome dev tools are being using with `$`, if jQuery is NOT loaded, `$` acts the same as `document.querySelector()` only returning the first element. Walmart uses React and may not even be loading jQuery.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Edge implements this too.

Answer (score 0):

Doing
`$('.search-result-gridview-items').children` seems to work for me

Answer (score -2):

Did you try using Child Selector (“parent > child”)?

```
$( ".search-product-result > li" )
```

Check more info here:
https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/hierarchy-selectors/

Comment: The `ul` has class `search-result-gridview-items`, so the `search-product-result` is the parent of the `ul` so this will not work as the `li` must be a direct child of a `ul`.